# IP address problem after messing with /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, ip

I have messed up my IP address. I had a dynamic IP that I changed to a static one. When I did that, the little icon in the corner of the screen that indicates a wired connection disappeared and was replaced by the wireless icon. Then, it started giving me problems so I decided to get a dynamic IP again. So I deleted everything in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file until only `auth eth0` was there. Now, I have an Ubuntu internal error message.

Comment: Okay, one note: **never** delete any system folder/file unless you are completely certain of what you are doing. If you aren't too certain, try renaming instead of deleting.

Comment: Please execute `ifconfig` and post the results

Comment: Yeah, I realised only too late that I shouldn't have deleted the files.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# this is the default.. 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# basically your lan usually named eth0 if had just one nic
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

if you want to set into static address just change the

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

t0

```
iface eth0 inet static
address www.xxx.yyy.zzz
netmask www.xxx.yyy.zzz
network www.xxx.yyy.zzz
broadcast www.xxx.yyy.zzz
dns-nameservers www.xxx.yyy.zzz
```

just for reminder.
make sure to make a back-up file everytime you change the file.